# Broken tool-tips in eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, linux-mint

I am not able to see tool-tips when hovering over variables. I have tried changing the Eclipse Mars theme but its not making a difference.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have tagged the question "mint" so I assume this is Eclipse on Linux with GTK. The problem may be a GTK3 bug (there are a few in Eclipse Mars unfortunately, some fixed for the upcoming Mars.2 release, some for Neon.0 in the summer).

You can try forcing GTK2 with an evironment variable before launching Eclipse. Set `SWT_GTK3=0` For example:

```
$ export SWT_GTK3=0
$ /path/to/eclipse -data /path/to/workspace
```